# How do I create a new tag?

Tags: support, tags, documentation-questions

I have an idea for a new tag. I think adding this tag would improve Server Fault. How do I add this tag? I am not finding documentation of how to do this.

Topics I would like to know about creating a new tag:

- What things should I check, to confirm that the tag is helpful and needed? For instance, I should probably check that there are existing questions which apply to this proposed tag.
- What is the reputation threshold to be able to create a tag?
- If I don't have enough reputation to create a tag myself, how should I propose it for someone else to create?  Post a question on Meta Server Fault, or do something else?
- If I do have sufficient reputation to create the tag, what button or UI do I look for to perform the tag creation?

(I think the details of the tag I have in mind don't matter. I don't want to discuss my proposed tag here. What I am looking for is some documentation about tag creation in general.)

Comment: It turns out this question is answered by two articles in the existing SF Help Center. However, I was not able to discover the Help Center when I came to Server Fault, then Meta Server Fault, with the question of "how do I create a new tag". I think that indicates a user experience design problem, that the Help Center content is not discoverable enough. I believe that adding links from the tag wiki for `[tags]` to the Help Center content will improve this situation.

Answer (score 2):

If you see a need for a new tag, consult [*Help Center* > *Privileges* >  *create tags*](https://serverfault.com/help/privileges/create-tags). There is advice there on evaluating if the proposed tag is appropriate to add. Create the tag by adding it to a question. To do this, you need to have the *Create Tags* privilege, which is awarded at 300 reputation on Server Fault. If you do not have this much reputation, post a question on [Meta Server Fault](https://meta.serverfault.com/) asking someone else to create it.

Some questions about how to use Server Fault are asked and answered on Meta Server Fault. But there is more information in the [*Help Center*](https://serverfault.com/help/). Searches in Meta Server Fault don't return results in the Help Center. You can find the Help Center via the link [*Help*] in the lower-left of Server Fault pages.

Comment: I have proposed adding the first paragraph of this answer to the Tag Info for `[tags]` in MSF. That will put the information in the place where I first tried to look for it.