# How to get a new tag added to Serverfault?

Tags: discussion

I would like to add the tag "NVLINK" to list of available tags. I don't have high enough reputation though.

NVLINK is a hardware based GPU to GPU data link created by Nivida. It is the basis of it's DGX and similar products, and it is used on the 2080 & 2080ti, and QUadro cards also.

Is there a process for adding new tags, for people like me?

Thanks!

Comment: Duplicate of https://meta.serverfault.com/q/9626/108333

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I create a new tag?](https://meta.serverfault.com/questions/9626/how-do-i-create-a-new-tag)

Answer (score 2):

I'am not against the tag creation as it target a video card for business PC/server, the quadro, which you don't see in home market PC normally, but I don't know if in some years only 2-3 questions might be tagged with that tag, as it's pretty niche.

I added the tag with your question, and another question which are Azure VM with a GPU.